# Update from 14.04 to 16.04 failed with GPG error

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates, gnupg

apt-get update after upgrade - I get following message

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

It did not help.

My current source.list:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to download from that repository as it kept asking for permissions, go to software and updates and check the unchecked update settings  and try again.

Comment: I don't have access to the GUI. Is there a console solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with a terminal way to alter the settings, but since you seem to have more than one issue. I'll advise you to download an image of 16.04.1 and install it, it will detect your settings from the previous install.

Comment: Are you behind a HTTP proxy by any chance? What's the output of `ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg* /usr/share/keyrings` and `dpkg-query -S /usr/share/keyrings | sed -e 's/:.*$//;s/, /\n/g' | xargs apt-cache policy`? By the way, none of these are actual errors, only warning or notes as shown by the `W:` and `N:`. You should be able to continue to use the package repositories albeit with the lack of securely signed repository data and packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it with `rm -rf /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*`

Apparently, gpg of some old repository was messing things up, despite those repositories being disabled..

Comment: If that fixed it for you, please mark it as an answer for it to be closed.

Comment: That fixed same problem for me. thx.