# Could we update the the instructions for "Update" in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates

Similar questions have been dealt with, but they are much earlier releases, and there seems to be a recurring and persistent problem with updating in 16.04.

My errors seem to move through.... (not exact wording)
"Failed to Download repository information"   (Update Fails)
"Requires installing from un-trusted sources"  (Update Fails)
"The information about available software is out of date"  (Update Fails)

I have tried several terminal commands to rebuild the repository list, and do not seem to be doing it correctly.

And along this same line, I am not able to get truefonts to install either, but that doesn't bother me as much except for the recurring error message.

I am not a terminal expert like some of you, but I understand that the command line is where we need to live.  So...  Go easy on me, but I am all ears to fix my install of 16.04.

Edit to add:  The output of "Sudo apt-get update" is:

When I run: sudo apt-get update   this is the output:

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Get:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [11.5 kB]           
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release     
Ign:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 463 kB in 6s (74.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thank you Gunnar for your patience with me.   This is the update after removing the Pidgin Poop.

```
john@Laptop:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for john: 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [11.5 kB]          
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Err:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
john@Laptop:~$
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your actual problem. **Exact** wording of possible error messages is a must.

Comment: If I use the GUI "Software Updater" it fails with "Failed to Download Repository Information, check your internet connection"

Comment: The software updater pops up with:  "Updated software is available for this computer. Do you want to install it now?"  If I select "Install" it fails with "Failed to DownLoad Repository Information, check your internet connection."

Comment: And just now it failed with "Requires installation from untrusted sources" and then exits.

Comment: Okay, open _Software & Updates_, select the tab _Other Software_ and remove or disable that pidgin-developers PPA. There are no Xenial packages there. Then run `sudo apt update` again and update your question with the new output.

Comment: OK..  Just FYI, when I open Sofware & Updates and disable the pidgin poop, i get the notice that "The information about available software is out of date"

Comment: Now check out http://askubuntu.com/q/849822 and run the command suggested in the answer there.

Comment: The Apt output shows a multitude of unrelated errors. The Q&A format of AskUbuntu works best if you ask one question so you can receive one answer. You fixed one of the issues using the linked question which is why I'm going to vote to close your question as a duplicate of it. Please [open a new follow-up question](/questions/ask) for the remaining issues and include the output of `apt-get update` or whatever seems relevant. Thanks.