# Unsigned repositories after running apt-get update (16.04)

Tags: apt, updates, repository, signature

Running `apt-get update` today refuses to update repositories as it doesn't think they are signed. At first it just gave the `At least one invalid signature was encountered` error for all repositories, but after trying to run `apt-get clean`, cleaning trusted.gpg.d, etc. it now says the repositories themselves are not signed.

I have tried several mirrors, and this same error comes from PPAs too. (I have removed them from the log)

How I can fix this?

```
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease   
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:3 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Err:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:4 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Err:3 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:4 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the accepted answer (or the clean && /apt/lists removal) didn't help in this case.

Comment: (my comment was an answer for now deleted comment suggesting that this is duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/849822/update-from-14-04-to-16-04-failed-with-gpg-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had accidentally littered busybox symlinks around my own filesystem. This caused apt-key's gpgv-method to fail and that caused the key errors.