# 22.04 - Errors on apt update after docker engine installation

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I tried to install the docker engine through the official documentation process here : https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

The process failed and now I cannot apt update :

```
nico@muninn  ~  sudo apt update
Réception de :1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Réception de :2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [109 kB]                    
Réception de :3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease [48,9 kB]                      
Réception de :4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99,8 kB]                
Err :3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
Réception de :5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Err :1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
Err :2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
Err :4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
Err :5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
W: Erreur de GPG : https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease : Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
E: Le dépôt https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease n'est pas signé.
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut.
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
W: Erreur de GPG : http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease : Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
E: Le dépôt http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease n'est pas signé.
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut.
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
W: Erreur de GPG : http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease : Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
E: Le dépôt http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease n'est pas signé.
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut.
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
W: Erreur de GPG : http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease : Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
E: Le dépôt http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease n'est pas signé.
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut.
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
W: Erreur de GPG : http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease : Au moins une signature non valable a été rencontrée.
E: Le dépôt http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease n'est pas signé.
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut.
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.
```

The sources.list file is the original one as it is a fresh install.

Finally I can not access my keys:

```
nico@muninn  ~  sudo apt-key list                                                          
create_gpg_home:trap:14: undefined signal: ABRT
```

Anybody knows how to deal with this ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update from 14.04 to 16.04 failed with GPG error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849822/update-from-14-04-to-16-04-failed-with-gpg-error)