# At least one invalid signature was encountered

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.04, update-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. After trying to run `sudo apt-get update`, like usual, I was faced with the following error messages:

```
Get:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [7547 B]
Err:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntumirror.dei.uc.pt/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When trying `apt-key list`:

```
daniel@bonnie:~$ apt-key list
create_gpg_home:trap:14: undefined signal: ABRT
```

If I try to, instead, update software through the Software Updater, I get the message:

> **Failed to download repository information**
> Check your Internet connection.

I'm not sure what is happening exactly, I tried to search online but only found one question similar to mine which was unanswered:

[22.04 - Errors on apt update after docker engine installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413978/22-04-errors-on-apt-update-after-docker-engine-installation)

Edit 1:
I also can't install any packages

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql
```

Edit 2: Tried to change the download server to the main server, still the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had changed my bash symbolic link and this was causing the problems.

After running the following command, the errors were fixed:

```
sudo ln -sf /bin/dash /bin/sh/
```